# How to implement a thread safe counter or increment in scala js

Tags: multithreading, scala.js

> JavaScript by itself is single-threaded.

Does this mean that we could simply write `var` counter in js project, and trust it to work properly?

```
//believe it's thread safe?
object ScalaObject{
   private var counter = 0L
   def get:Long = {
     counter = counter + 1
     counter
   }
}
```

I'm not from javascript world. I want to make it sure.

Adding `@volatile` or `synchronized` does not cause an error to compiler. And seems not to affect compiled js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that we could simply write var counter in js project, and trust it to work properly?

Yes.

It's also fun to read [the implementation of `AtomicLong`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/javalib/src/main/scala/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.scala) in Scala.js. You will see that it's just a simple stupid `var`, with a lot of ceremony to comply to the interface.

Comment: This may deserve a line in www.scala-js.org